# "Wrong type argument: stringp, cons" when calling apply function on concatenated lists

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wanted to write some functionality in Emacs which will allow me to run my favorite editor and file manager in directory where my current buffer file resides. I'm not familiar with Lisp so this code may be ugly, anyway:

```
(setq terminal-program "rxvt-unicode")

(defun buffer-dir-name ()
  (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))

(defun terminal-option-buffer-dir ()
  (let ((dir (format "'%s'" (buffer-dir-name))))
    `("-cd" ,dir)))

(setq terminal-option-ranger '("-e" "ranger"))

(defun run-terminal ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process "terminal" nil terminal-program) (terminal-option-buffer-dir))

;; outdated, see below
(defun run-file-manager ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((args (append (terminal-option-buffer-dir) terminal-option-ranger)))
    (message (type-of args)
    (apply 'start-process "filemanager" nil terminal-program args))))
```

Function run-terminal works fine. But when I try to run run-file-manager I'm experiencing following error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, cons`. Why? Documentation says that return value of `append` function is a list, not cons.

---

After Drew response I saw that `run-file-manager` function has some trash left after my debugging. Now it looks as follow:

```
(defun run-file-manager ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((args (append (terminal-option-buffer-dir) terminal-option-ranger)))
    (apply 'start-process "filemanager" nil terminal-program args)))
;;  (apply 'start-process "filemanager" nil terminal-program '("-cd" "/opt/" "-e" "ranger"))))
```

Now I have an another issue. When I call this function it does nothing. But if first invocation of `apply` is commented and second one is uncommented it works as I expect: it runs `ranger` in terminal in */opt* directory. Any ideas?

---

I solved my problem, which was slightly different from that in question title. Problem was that function `terminal-option-buffer-dir` was returning `-cd` option with valued starting with `'` not `/` which is required by urxvt.
I debugged that by setting parameter `BUFFER` of `start-process` function to `"*Messages*"`.

Comment: set `debug-on-error` to `t` (manually or in the options menu) and post the backtrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error msg says that something in `run-file-manager` was expecting a string and got the symbol `cons` instead.

`message` expects a string as its first argument. But `type-of` returns a symbol. In this case, it returns the symbol `cons`.